# Intersection of closed sub schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a family of closed sub schemes, $ \phi_ i: Z_ i\rightarrow X $ the scheme intersection $\phi:\cap_ i Z_ i \rightarrow X$ is defined to be the closed sub scheme of X such that for each affine open $ U \subset X $, the kernel of  $\mathscr{O}_ X(U)\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{\cap_ i Z_ i} (\phi^{-1}( U)) $ is the ideal generated by the kernels of all the $ \mathscr{O}_X(U)\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{Z_ i} (\phi_ i^{-1}( U)) $ .  My question is whether the same is true when U is is not necessarily affine. That is for all open subsets of X.

Comment: Try the case when $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ and $Z$ any proper closed subscheme and $U=X$.

Comment: @Mohan  I’m sorry I don’t understand.    Do you want me to intersect Z with X or intersect Z with some other proper closed Z? In the cases I know $ Z\subset P^n_k $ Will have Global ring of functions equal to k.

Comment: So the map from $O_X(X)\to O_Z(Z\cap U)$ has kernel just zero.

Comment: @Mohan right, if you take U=X, it seems like the statement is always true since all kernels from $O_X(X)=k$ are zero... but i thought you were gesturing at a counterexample. have i misunderstood?

Comment: @Mohan +1 request to elaborate.

Comment: Sorry I see now the intersection can be the zero scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two counterexamples:

1. $Z_1, Z_2$ disjoint closed subschemes of $U=X=\mathbb{P}^n$ e.g. $Z_1=\{{0\}}, Z_2=\{{\infty\}}, U=X=\mathbb{P}^1$.
2. $U=X=\mathbb{A}^2-\{{(0,0)\}}, Z_1=(y=0), Z_2=(y-x^2-x=0)$.