# closed subscheme not onto for global functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a simple example of a closed subscheme $X\rightarrow Y $ such that $\mathscr{O}_ Y(Y)\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X(X)$         is not onto?

(Sort of related to this question [Intersection of closed sub schemes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498064/intersection-of-closed-sub-schemes), but not really comparable)

Comment: Two points on the projective line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field, and $P_1=\sum_{i=0}^d{a_iU^i} \in k[U]$ be irreducible with degree $d > 1$ (it’s possible as soon as $k$ isn’t algebraically closed).

Let $P=\sum_{i=0}^d{a_iU^iV^{d-i}} \in k[U,V]$. $Y=\mathbb{P}^1_k$, and $X=V_+(P)$.

Then $X \rightarrow Y$ is a closed immersion of $k$-schemes and $O_Y(Y)=k$.

Now, let $p \in X$, then $p$ is a prime homogeneous ideal of $k[U,V]$ containing $P$ and not containing $\{U,V\}$. Assume $Y \in p$. Then $a_dU^d \in p$ hence $U,V \in p$, a contradiction. So $X \subset D_+(U)$.

It follows that $X$ is the spectrum of $(k[U,V]_V)/(Pk[U,V]_V)=k[U]/P_1$ which is a field extension $K$ of $k$.

So $X \rightarrow Y$ induces $k \rightarrow K$ in global sections, not surjective.